# Aggregate functions in DAO

Tags: java, database, hibernate, service, dao

I have some simple Domain Model which describes persons table in db:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "persons")
public class Person {

private int id;
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private int age;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

@Column
public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

@Column
public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}

public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

@Column
public int getAge() {
    return age;
}

public void setAge(int age) {
    this.age = age;
}

}
```

Also i have some DAO class which works with this model:

```
class PersonDao {
// getById
// add
// remove
// etc
}
```

Also i have some service, which works with this PersonDAO:

```
class PersonService {
//
}
```

In this service i want to get "COUNT(*)", "MAX(age)", "MIN(age)" from DAO, using some criteria(by first name as example).
What is the correct way to do this?

1. Define 3 different methods in DAO (like getCount(firstname),
   getMin(firstname), getMax(firstname)) - very bad way, because it will
   execute 3 different queries with WHERE statement and it is very slow
   with big data.
2. Define some model like "PersonsInfo" with these 3
       fields and return this model from single query - i think bad way, because this model is not Domain Model.

So, what is the correct way to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using Hibernate for the DAO layer, using a non persistent model (second suggested way) for obtaining the three fields is a bad way as you said.
It's acceptable then to go with the first choice and let Hibernate do the work for you and execute the aggregate functions. For performance issues, Hibernate guys recommend handling these kinds of cases using HQL or criteria queries.[Hibernate Documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html/associations.html#assoc-complex)